# Missing ] after element list - Javascript append method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a dynamic drop-down menu related to my project thanks to this line of javascript :

```
$("#navbar-item-1").append(`<a class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="changeMyCurrentMap('${tabName[j]}','${tabLat[j]}','${tabLon[j]}', ${tabMarkerList[j]})">${tabName[j]}</a>`);
```

When we click on one of the buttons contained in the navbar(Bootstrap3), we activate the changeMyCurrentMap function which is represented by this prototype :

```
function changeMyCurrentMap(name, lat, lon, markerList);
```

*name*, *lat* and *lon* are respectively a string and 2 double. *markerList* is an object list.

When I call changeMyCurrentMap with onclick, all parameters are passed correctly, except the array (so markerList) which returns this error :

**SyntaxError: missing ] after element list.**

I've already read many posts about this type of error but I still can't find where my problem could be.
Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: why don't you add click listener to element in js itself instead of onclick attribute. It won't work as the attribute can't hold array or object values without stringifying

Comment: seems line one of the these value return object..

tabName = [0]
tabLat = [0]
tabLon = [0]
tabMarkerList = [0]

`console.log("%s", tabMarkerList[j])`

try `console.log` values

Comment: @Anees Ijaz I don't have a fluent JavaScript at all so if I understand correctly, it is not possible to use an object array with this kind of syntax in an onclick ?

Comment: @xdeepakv I've printed tabMarkerList and it returns : [object Object], [object Object].

Comment: @Akumalex anees is saying, i can keep only index in function. when u call, use iedex to get value. Clear way.

Comment: i found the issue,,, , '${tabMarkerList[j]}' missing single quote`'`.

Comment: @Akumalex: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the easiest solution will be to stringify the array and then parse it.

something like this:

```js
$("#navbar-item-1").append(`<a class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="changeMyCurrentMap_('${tabName[j]}','${tabLat[j]}','${tabLon[j]}', '${JSON.stringify(tabMarkerList[j])}')">${tabName[j]}</a>`);

// note this is not the changeMyCurrentMap function but is another middleware function to pass correct data to changeMyCurrentMap
function changeMyCurrentMap_(a, b, c){
    changeMyCurrentMap(a, b, JSON.parse(c))
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code thank you, now the dropdown-item is like the following :

Comment: <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="changeMyCurrentMap_('Boony à Paris','48.8566969','2.3514616', [{" contentjson": ....... }}])"="">Boony à Paris</a>

Comment: can you check console ? if there is any error ... and also console the 3rd parameter value in you function and check what is the output of that

Comment: But it still print the error : **SyntaxError: missing ] after element list**

Answer (score 0):

Instead for add all value in HTML, u can just write index and use the same index in call back function. Check two examples, doing the same. One without and other using the index.

```js
$(function () {
  const tabName = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"];
  const tabLat = ["tabLat1", "tabLat2", "tabLat3"];
  const tabMarkerList = ["tabMarkerList1", "tabMarkerList2", "tabMarkerList3"];
  const tabLon = ["tablon1", "tablon2", "tablon3"];
  window.changeMyCurrentMap = (name, lat, lon, mark) => {
    console.log(name, lat, lon, mark);
  };
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    $("#navbar-item-1").append(
      `<li><a class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="changeMyCurrentMap('${tabName[j]}','${tabLat[j]}','${tabLon[j]}', '${tabMarkerList[j]}')">${tabName[j]}</a></li>`
    );
  }
  window.changeMyCurrentMapIndex = (index) => {
    console.log(
      tabName[index],
      tabLat[index],
      tabLon[index],
      tabMarkerList[index]
    );
  };
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    $("#navbar-item-2").append(
      `<li><a class="dropdown-item" type="button" onclick="changeMyCurrentMapIndex(${j})">${tabName[j]}</a></li>`
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Without index</p>
    <ul id="navbar-item-1"></ul>
    <p>With index</p>
    <ul id="navbar-item-2"></ul>
```